Elsevier API: resolve PII to DOI
I would like to resolve Elsevier's PII for journals articles to DOI.
I've successfully used the their retrieval API to resolve PII to DOI for articles published by Elsevier. For instance, I can resolve S2468023024002402 to 10.1016/j.surfin.2024.104081 via https://api.elsevier.com/content/object/pii/S2468023024002402
However, when I try to resolve PII for third-party content, like from Wiley, using the same API endpoint (https://api.elsevier.com/content/object/pii/S1615415023009147), I encounter an error stating "The resource specified cannot be found," even though the PII is known to Elsevier (https://www.sciencedirect.com/org/science/article/abs/pii/S1615415023009147).
Are there any alternative API endpoints or methods I could use to resolve PII to DOI for third-party content?
